# Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, database, yii, orm, frameworks

I am using the Yii framework and having the following Yii error with the database when attempting an insert into a table - I can see that the user with the user_id of '5702157058' exists in my 'myuser' table so not sure why I am getting this error?

```
<h1>CDbException</h1>
<p>CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:       
1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mydb`.`organisation_news_read`, 
CONSTRAINT `FK_organisation_news_read_myuser` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `myuser_`
(`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION). The SQL statement executed was: 
INSERT INTO `organisation_news_read` (`news_id`, `user_id`) VALUES (:yp0, :yp1). 
Bound with :yp0=287, :yp1='5702157058'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following points,

```
1. First check your foreign key field name and its spelling are same.
2. then check your model relation function
3. check your table field are same
4. check the DB engine is it INNODB?
```

mostly your foreign key setup have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Check the relationship between 'users' and 'organisation_news_read' surely this is the problem.
Try this to validate if exists.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 5702157058;
```

This should find a row.

I think your tables are like these. (this example is in postgres by the way)

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  name character varying(50),
  last_name character varying(50),
  CONSTRAINT pk_users PRIMARY KEY (id)
)



CREATE TABLE organisation_news_read
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  users_id integer,
  CONSTRAINT pk_organisation PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_organisation_vs_users FOREIGN KEY (users_id)
      REFERENCES users (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

hope this helps